# выброс исключения без имени

Tags: c++, ооп, исключения

Почему не отлавливается исключение?

```
class A
{
public:
    void SHOW()
    {
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
        throw;
    }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        A* ptr = new A;
        ptr->SHOW();
    }
    catch (...)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Какое** исключение?
Оператор `throw` без аргумента означает "сгенерировать перехваченное исключение заново" и применяется только в блоке `catch`.

Если бы вы написали что-то типа `throw 0` или `throw "Error"` - дело другое. А так...

Вот ситуация, где ваш `throw` действительно сработает:

```
class A
{
public:
    void SHOW()
    {
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
        throw;
    }
};

int main()
{
    try {
        A* ptr = new A;
        try
        {
            throw 5;
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            ptr->SHOW();
        }
    } catch(int x)
    {
        cout << x << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему тогда компилятор не выдал ошибку, что применение `throw` в данном контексте невозможно из-за отсутствия соответствующего блока `catch()`?

Comment: @Arhad Я дописал пример, который показывает, что такой `throw` может иметь смысл. А отлавливать, есть ли `catch`, компилятор не обязан - может, эта функция будет вызвана где-то в совершенно ином файле? Как не отлавливает и - есть ли `try-catch` вокруг обычного `throw` с аргументом.

Comment: А, понял, `catch()` должен быть не прямо в той же функции, что и `throw`, а где-нибудь выше по стеку вызовов.

Comment: @Arhad: Если там снаружи `catch` или нет - характеристика *времени выполнения*: ответ на вопрос зависит от фактического контекста вызовов, которые привели к вызов `SHOW()`. Компилятор не может отлавливать ошибки времени выполнения. Да и "ошибкой" это не является. Такой `throw` без активного исключения вызовет `terminate()`. А может быть вы именно этого и хотели.

Comment: *А почему тогда компилятор не выдал ошибку, что применение throw в данном контексте невозможно из-за отсутствия соответствующего блока catch()*

Анастасия, выдадут языки типа С# и Java